# Having troubles connecting my kubernetes engine application to google cloud sql instance using sidecar method

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm pretty new to Kubernetes and google cloud and am trying to deploy my dropwizard microservice to the cloud. I have a mysql instance set up on the cloud with all the secrets and service account created. Whenever I create the deployment and the load balancer and then get the logs, it throws the communication links failure error. The config file in the image in my container registry is set to use localhost as the host.
Here's the yml file for my deployment

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: users-service
  name: users-service
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: users-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: users-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/users-service-289022/users-service:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: users-service-container
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: app-port
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8081
              name: admin-port
              protocol: TCP
          env:
          - name: DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: username
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: password
          resources: {}
        - name: cloudsql-proxy
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
          command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                    "-instances=lusers-service-289022:us-east1:mysql-db=tcp:3306",
                    "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
              mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
              readOnly: true
            - name: ssl-certs
              mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
            - name: cloudsql
              mountPath: /cloudsql
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
        - name: cloudsql
          emptyDir:
        - name: ssl-certs
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/ssl/certs
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
```

This is the output from the logs:

```
Causing: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
!
! The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
! at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:83)
! at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:204)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:975)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:843)
! ... 26 common frames omitted
! Causing: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
!
! The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:166)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:58)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:853)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
! at io.dropwizard.db.ManagedPooledDataSource.start(ManagedPooledDataSource.java:37)
! at io.dropwizard.lifecycle.JettyManaged.doStart(JettyManaged.java:27)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
! at com.cb.CBUsersService.main(CBUsersService.java:30)
INFO  [2020-09-12 15:57:23,835] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started application@3069a360{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
WARN  [2020-09-12 15:57:23,846] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool@dw-admin{STOPPED,1<=0<=64,i=0,q=0} rejected org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$167/0x0000000800e08040@7f6329cb
ERROR [2020-09-12 15:57:23,848] io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand: Unable to start server, shutting down
! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
! at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
! at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:503)
! at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:492)
! at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
! at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
! at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
! at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
! ... 29 common frames omitted
! Causing: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
!
! The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
! at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
! at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:83)
! at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:204)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:975)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:843)
! ... 26 common frames omitted
! Causing: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
!
! The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:166)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:58)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:853)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
! at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
! at io.dropwizard.db.ManagedPooledDataSource.start(ManagedPooledDataSource.java:37)
! at io.dropwizard.lifecycle.JettyManaged.doStart(JettyManaged.java:27)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
! ... 7 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:413)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
! at com.cb.CBUsersService.main(CBUsersService.java:30)
! Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$167/0x0000000800e08040@7f6329cb
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.execute(QueuedThreadPool.java:385)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.execute(SelectorManager.java:167)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.doStart(ManagedSelector.java:99)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:305)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:276)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:238)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
!       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:428)
!       ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You will have to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63862249/edit) and include the actual log output, as no one can _guess_ what is wrong with your setup

Comment: Do you have logs of the other container (of the Cloud SQL proxy container)?

Comment: To progress this case can you tell us more about create the deployment and the load balancer? Are you following a tutorial?